# Why Java program not terminating

Tags: java, concurrency, future, executors

The code below checks the usage of `ExecutorCompletionService` from `Java Concurrency` framework (the IDE being used is Netbeans).

But the program doesn't terminate. Why?

### Code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class TestFuture {

    public static void main(String... args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        Executor ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        CompletionService<Long> cs = new ExecutorCompletionService<Long>(ex);
        cs.submit(new Worker());
        cs.submit(new Worker());
        cs.submit(new Worker());
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            long l = cs.take().get();
            //utilize the result
            System.out.println(l);
        }
    }
}

class Worker implements Callable {

    @Override
    public Long call() throws Exception {
        //do some task and return back
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to halt(shutdown) the thread pool, or specify threads as daemon.

Comment: using `ExecutorService#shutdown()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Threads in thread pool will keep running when `main` is finished. That's why JVM won't shut down. You need to either use daemon-threads, or shutdown the pool explicitly.

Here's an example:

```
ExecutorService ex = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
// do all your submission work here
ex.shutdown();
```

Comment: thanks. in the examples that i saw on internet, they never mentioned to shutdown the the threadpool, and the examples were using `Executor` which does not have a `shutdown/halt` behavior. :)

Comment: Also, awaitTermination() if you need to block until the threads are actually stopped - shutdown() returns immediately.